# grouping items without duplicating logic

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, imperative-programming

When programming imperatively I often find myself writing code to groups items like this:

```
function group(items):
    groups <- new Groups
    curGroup <- new Group
    for item in items:
        if item doesn't belong in curGroup:
            if curGroup is good:
                add curGroup to groups
            curGroup <- new Group
        add item to curGroup
    if curGroup is good:
        add curGroup to groups
    return groups
```

Unfortunately this code suffers from a few deficiencies:

- The `if curGroup is good: add curGroup to groups` code is duplicated. While the condition in the conditional can be broken out into a function, the logic to invoke that function and add curGroups to groups still appears twice and it's easy to forget the second occurrence.
- The logic to create a new group appears twice. This logic may be trivial, and if it isn't then it can be broken out into a separate function, but like with the first bullet point, it indicates that the flow is incorrect.
- It's possible that the first item fails the belong check, in which case we create a new group right after creating a new group. This issue may seem trivial but it occasionally requires explicitly preventing the initial empty group from being added to `groups`. Regardless, it suggests incorrect expression of the desired logic.

I am wondering whether there is a cleaner way to express this logic. I apologize for the abstract nature of this question but this problem appears in multiple contexts. If it is necessary to address this issue in the context of a particular programming language, you can assume Java.

Comment: I don't think this should really be tagged Java, your pseudocode isn't Java, and since you are talking about algorithm structure and flow it doesn't really matter what language people answer in right? You say people should assume Java, but why?

Comment: @KevinWells Fundamentally the question applies to any imperative programming language. However many times questions receive comments for more concrete details and the exact tools available to solve the problem may depend on the language. I can remove the Java mention and tag but I would then expect to be asked for more context.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it is a valid question without talking about the specific language (since it is really more about good coding practices), but I understand the impulse to avoid anything that might be called out later

Comment: @KevinWells At the very least I can change the order of the tags so that `algorithm` is the primary tag. Edit: that doesn't appear to work. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to split the `is good` group filter off from the grouping loop -- treating it as a post-process, or a demand-driven one.  You could argue that combining the two (as shown in your question) is an example of premature optimization causing awkward code.

If you make an outer loop iterate over `Group`'s, with an inner `while item` loop, you can naturally avoid duplicating your `new Group` code.  It also should help finesse your first-item concern, by making it easier to treat the first item in the group differently from the rest:

```
function group(items):
    groups <- new Groups
    while(items not empty):
        curGroup <- new Group
        using items:
            add current item to curGroup
            advance to next item
        while(items not empty):
            using items:
                if current item belongs in curGroup:
                    add current item to curGroup
                    advance to next item
                else exit inner loop
        if(curGroup is good):
            add curGroup to groups
    return groups
```

Note that the above pseudocode is using `items` as an iterator.

Even though your question is about imperative programming, it might be instructive to look at the Haskell implementation of `groupBy`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say to iterate over groups. The groups are totally empty to begin with, so in what would you do while iterating over nothing?

Comment: I mean, each iteration of the outer loop should create and fill one group, and (possibly) add it to `Groups`.

Comment: Maybe adding pseudo code for what you mean would help because that still doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: This suggestion makes a lot of sense. Then the only duplicated logic would be `add group to allGroups`, which would appear both in and right after the grouping loop. The scope of the code smell would be reduced but not eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this would be to add an additional condition to your first `if` statement, such that it encompasses the logic of the final `if` statement. I would make sure it added `curGroup` to `group` if either the item doesn't belong in the current group, or if I am on the last `item` in `items`.

This isn't a massive improvement (it is still eight lines of code, and I don't like the weirdly nested `if` statements), but I can't think of a better solution at the moment.

It solves your three concerns pretty well:

1. The `if curGroup is good: add curGroup to groups` is no longer duplicated
2. The add `Group` to `Groups` is also no longer duplicated
3. This is not solved directly by my reorganization. However, you can easily avoid problem 3 by making sure that you always say an item belongs in a group when the group is empty (which makes sense to me, but I don't know the details of what your grouping is actually doing).

Here is what that might look like:

```
function group(items):
    groups <- new Groups
    curGroup <- new Group
    for item in items: 
        if item doesn't belong in curGroup || item is last item:
            if item is last item:
                add item to curGroup
            if curGroup is good:
                add curGroup to groups
            curGroup <- new Group
        add item to curGroup
    return groups
```

I would be happy to see a better, more refined solution than this, but I thought I would post this to at least get things rolling

Update:

Here is a different direction you could take this (if it works in Java, I am more accustomed to C#). Instead of building a group of groups, build a Hash Map (I'm going to call it dictionary since that is what it is in C#), with the key being some value you calculate to determine which group an item belongs in, and the value being a group of items. The function to determine which group an item belongs to should be very similar to how you currently check if an item belongs in the current gruop.

Then your code would look like this:

```
function group(items):
    groups <- new Dictionary<string, Group>
    for item in items:
        groupKey <- item.FindKey()
        if !groups.ContainsKey(groupKey):
            add new group to groups with key of groupKey
        add item to groups[groupKey]
    return groups
```

Advantages to this approach:

1. No duplicated code
2. It doesn't matter what order the items are in, whereas before that did matter (this may be a disadvantage in some cases, if that is so, let me know, there are ways around that).
3. Easy to see why an item belongs to a given group (makes for easier debugging)

Disadvantages

1. As mentioned before, order may be important to preserve
2. Uses a more complicated data structure (though a HashMap/Dictionary is not that complicated)
3. It may be hard to write a `FindKey` function for items (though I suspect it wouldn't be in most cases)

Comment: This answer does address point 1 but you still have logic to create a new group twice so it doesn't address point 2. The real issue with this answer in practice is that it is awkward to determine whether an item is the last item. In Java I couldn't just use a foreach loop: I would have to also have a counter or use an iterator. Also the step `add item to `curGroup` appears twice which, while trivial, indicates awkward flow.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I added a totally different approach in case that is more applicable to your situation, and one that solves all three of your concerns